# css - problems with negative margin in mail template

Tags: html, css, email, gmail, yahoo-mail

I'm creating a html mail template, I used a ribbon so I need to a move it a little bit past border. you can see the code here: http://jsfiddle.net/GEqk7/

To do this first i used `position: relative;` and I gave the ribbons a negative position but the thing is that `position` is not well supported by gmail and yahoo and ... . So I decided to use negative margin but it looks like gmail and yahoo don't support that either.

is there a way or a fallback to to do this?

Comment: You should really classify your elements and use CSS to organize your formatting. That fiddle is scary. (Very fitting for Halloween)

Comment: @Agony sorry :D mail agents just support inline css so I had to make it look like this, Happy Halloween by the way :D

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Most of the Email clients dont support negative margin. You will have to take that ribbon image as a background.

Answer (score 8):

As of Jan. 2015, gmail's web client ignores negative margin.

Answer (score 4):

Apparently, as of Jan. 2023, Gmail's web client still ignores negative margin

Answer (score 3):

Apparently, as of Jan. 2022, Gmail's web client still ignores negative margin

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, as of Jul 26, 2023, Gmail's web client still ignores negative margin

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, as of Jan 08, 2024, Gmail's web client still ignores negative margin

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35496561)

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, as of Mar. 1, 2024, Gmail's web client still ignores negative margin